# Find $\int_Ly^2\,ds$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find $$\int_L(y^2)\,ds.$$ where $L$ is the arch of the parabola $y^2=2x$ and its limits are $0$ $(0;0)$ and $A(1;2)$.

I have no Idea how to do this..can you give me a hint?

Comment: Counterexample: $\int_L y ds$ is shorter.

Comment: Please, make titles informative.

Comment: What do you know about line integrals?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** 
$$ds=\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2} \,dx= \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{dx}{dy}\right)^2 }\,dy.$$

Comment: yes but how do I relate O and A to this?

Comment: You will end up integrating with respect to $x$ or $y$, whichever looks easiest. If, for example, it is $x$, then you will be integrating from $x=0$ to $x=1$. The points $O$ and $E$ tell us the interval of integration.